# Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I'm getting this error in android studio, how can I fix it?
What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\ZEYNEP\AndroidStudioProjects\app\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\ZEYNEP.gradle\caches\7.5\scripts\3d075fs9hjp81ny0sgym4v09w).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 63

Answer (score 0):

I was using java jdk19, but android studio electric eel does not support java jdk19 yet, so I installed java jdk17. I have edited the paths for java jdk17, the problem has been solved.